# Facing Issue with settingup MarkLogic 2 node cluster.

Tags: marklogic

As I am new to MarkLogic and I am having free developer license, am  trying to create 2 Node Cluster for MarkLogic server. I have installed it on one machine but when I am trying to add one more machine to my server. It is not working. I think as we are not having DNS on our CentOS machine.It is not working because it might be looking for DNS. 2nd machine not able to find 1st(my) machine, it keeps on seaching for my host info. So can we force it to take host name info from /etc/hosts file? Please suggest what I need to do.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Probably belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

Setup both machines for either DNS or /etc/hosts.
Make sure from both machines you can ping the other machine using the same machine name.
Then you should be able to join a cluster.

Comment: Can't one use IP number instead of DNS name?

Comment: I tried with giving IP and AssetID info in /etc/hosts. But Same issue is there...it keeps on seaching for my host info i.e. restartin server for some time and after that It ended with Connection Timed Out. Please suggest